# Prefix a ">" in front of each line in a text (ie. create "quote" blocks)

Tags: php, string

I have this text, in a string:

```
Original Message
Message was quoted 
Other text Message
Other text Message
Message was quoted
```

I would like to add ">" in front of each line in the text:

```
>Original Message
>Message was quoted 
>Other text Message
>Other text Message
>Message was quoted
```

How would I go about doing this in php?

Comment: +1 Having this being at -1 without any reason is bad. I liked the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `$string`:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\n/", "\n>", $string);
```

should do it.

Comment: Or you could just use str_replace.

Comment: This is great but how can I also do it to the first line.

Comment: @JimmyB $string = '>' . str_replace("\n", "\n>", $string);  I believe should do the trick.

Comment: What Method would be faster `$string =  ">" . preg_replace("/\n/", "\n>",     $string);`                                                                  
`$string = '>' . str_replace("\n", "\n>", $string);`

Comment: For the size of the string in question, it probably won't make a noticeable difference either way.

Comment: According to php's manual page for str_replace, they suggest you should always use it over preg_replace unless you need regexes, so I'm guessing use that. I'm just in the habit of using preg_replace for things because more often than not I DO use regexes, so in my case it's what I need to use. :)